# Problems with Programatically selecting checkbox nodes

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtree

I have a checkbox group Listed in a tree structure.The tree is connected with a vector, which stores the state of checkboxes in the tree. I have buttons to select all checkboxes, and other buttons to select the corresponding checkbox. From the below diagram you can picturize UI.

[image]

```
for (CheckBoxNode Node : CheckBoxNodeTree.checkBoxRows) {
if(Node.isSelected()){
Node.setSelected(!Node.isSelected());
        }
```

For Select All the code used is :

```
TreeModel model = TREE.getModel();
        TreeNode  rootofTree = (TreeNode) model.getRoot();

        Enumeration<TreeNode> enumeratorForTree =                ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)rootofTree).breadthFirstEnumeration();
        while (enumeratorForTree.hasMoreElements()) {
         TreeNode child = enumeratorForTree.nextElement();
         Object currentNode = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) child).getUserObject();
         if(currentNode instanceof CheckBoxNode) {

                ((CheckBoxNode) currentNode).setSelected(true);
         }
        }
        for (CheckBoxNode Node: CheckBoxNodeTree.checkBoxRows) 
        {
        Node.setSelected(true);
        }
```

The issue i am facing now is that on clicking the respective buttons the checkbox state changes, but after clicking "Select All" button i am able to see that the nodes get checked ,but after this , if i try to select the induvidual nodes using the corresponding button , i cannot see the result on the tree .
Can anyone Help me with your suggestions. Thanks to the replier in advance.

Comment: Is that a typo?  You are using different enumerations.                while (enumeratorForTree.hasMoreElements()) {
         TreeNode child = enumeratorForColumnTree.nextElement();

Comment: I'm not quite clear on your question. Nothing mentions when you are clearing the check boxes? Somewhere you have to set them back to false? Checking an already checked box is a no-op?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a notification issue - you are changing node state without the model knowing of it. Assuming your model is a DefaultTreeModel, invoke a model.nodeChanged after changing the selection:

```
currentNode.setSelected(newState);
model.nodeChanged(currentNode);
```

Comment: learning item of day I'd be sure that XxxEditor notified DefaultXxxModel +1

Comment: @mKorbel - the editor does (in fact it's the tree's CellEditorListener somehwere in the ui delegate), but here the question (as I understood it) is about _programmatically_ changing the node state

Comment: agreed to question, but I'd be sure untill this moment that Enumeration changed every JComponents in the Node and all code that I have works without that, interesting, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code for your buttons used to select individual nodes?  Are you trying to make a button that toggles but yours only checks the box right now?  Maybe try this:

```
 buttonPushed() {
     //get your node for this button
    node.setSelected(!node.isSelected());
 }
```

Comment: Actualy , after doing the select all i can see the nodes getting checked . But after doing this , if we press any of the other buttons ,  i am not able to see the corresponding change in the corresponding node .